# Getting external Token into my Angular application

Tags: angularjs, rest, http

My http server framework is serving a static (Angular) SPA.

To authenticate users, they will need to enter their email adress and submit it. They receive a link per email in the form of https://www.somedomain.com/?token=123456789 (inspired by passwordless.net). For later accesses, the token will be stored with localStorage.

My problem is: I have no solid idea how the SPA can learn about that token. Of course, the user may copy&paste that token. Or I can embed that token within the served HTML, but I don't see that being very elegant or even fast, and possible not very secure either.

Is there a simple way to do this I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using '$location', then you can simply parse the '$location.url()' and get the token.
If you are using the '$routeProvider', then you can define the routeProvider configuration like this:

```
$routeProvider.when('/reset_password/:token', { /*controller and template conf here*/ })
```

And in your controller:

```
var theToken = $routeParams.token;
```

Comment: Simple and precise. Would something like this work in Angular 2 too?